# Creating a React Component UI Library with code splitting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rollupjs, code-splitting, lerna

We're in the beginning stages of this project, so right now we're just trying to figure out how best to start.

We want to create a UI library of React components, and what we'd like to do is create the library so that you can import just one element directly, so that:

```
// bad
import {Button} from '@mycompany/uilib'
// good
import Button from '@mycompany/uilib/Button'
```

That's the big question. So we're looking at a couple of solutions to start - we've taken a look at [create-react-library](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library) and [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) or [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) might be better starts?

Here's what we're looking for, from a business & engineering perspective.

- We all think Typescript is the way to go.
- We *think* that rollup might be better for this type of project than Webpack, but we're not entirely sure. It may be worth a little overhead if it increases dev turnaround and is easier to maintain/configure.

But the big question is that I'm not sure how packages like, say, '@material-ui/core/Button' do it.  Googling hasn't helped much, thus the appeal to the StackOverflow gurus.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Brian were you able to solve this? I'm also curious how material ui does it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd suggest sticking with the well-written and supported [create-react-app with TypeScript support](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript). This gets a lot of the initial config out of the way.

Then, I'd encourage you to have a look at a combo of [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) and Lerna. Setup can be tricky, but the automated symlinks, and the ability for your individual components (packages) to depend on each other, makes this a powerful combo.

On the dev cycle and "playground" front, Storybook is hard to beat. They have some [amazing stuff coming soon](https://medium.com/storybookjs/storybook-docs-sneak-peak-5be78445094a) around docs, which will be quite powerful (and visually pleasing)

Let me know if you have any more questions - this topic is front-of-mind for me at the moment, so my head is swimming with ideas.